# "bash: *.py: command not found" when I run "heroku run worker"

Tags: python, heroku, tweepy

I'm trying to make a twitter bot by using python, tweepy, and heroku,
and here's my python script.

```
import tweepy, codecs, time

CONSUMER_KEY = '***************'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '*****************************'
ACCESS_KEY = '******************************'
ACCESS_SECRET = '****************************'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

fileObj=codecs.open('zegal.txt','r','utf-8')
f=fileObj.readlines()
fileObj.close()

for line in f:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(900)
```

this works when I run "python zegal.py",
but it doesn't work when I run "heroku run worker".
it says "bash: zegal.py: command not found" even though I have
zegal.py, zegal.txt, procfile, requirements.txt all in the same folder.

I wrote "worker: zegal.py" in the procfile
and "tweepy==3.5.0" in the requirements.txt file.

I have a heroku app, and because my textfile has Korean sentences,
I think I have to use codecs.open and utf-8.

I searched for days to fix this problem, but none of those solutions helped.
I added the working directory to path of environment variable, and
I tried "import os.path" for example,

```
scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(scriptpath, 'zegal.txt')
fileObj=codecs.open(filename,'r','utf-8')
f=fileObj.readlines()
fileObj.close()
```

but that doesn't work neither. How can I solve this? I'm complete beginner.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write full command to execute in Procfile

```
worker: python zegal.py
```

Writing just filename of python script won't work. You can see an example in Heroku docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

Comment: oh, that's what I tried before, and it worked! I just thought there would be another way to execute without "python". of course you know I was wrong. now i write full command as you said. I appreciate that.